# Attempting to restore this backup may encounter storage space problems & Exclusive access Error

Tags: sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012, restore

I would like to say that as one of POS database when i am try to `Restore verifyonly from disk=N'C:\POS Backup File\SLQ.bak';` from TSQL.
I am getting the below message like this.

> Attempting to restore this backup may encounter storage space
>   problems. Subsequent messages will provide details. The path specified
>   by `"C:\Software Lab\Database\SLQ.mdf"` is not in a valid directory.
>   Directory lookup for the file `"C:\Software Lab\Database\SLQ_Log.ldf"`
>   failed with the `operating system error 3`(The system cannot find the
>   path specified.). The backup set on file 1 is valid.

Let i am briefly explaining the POS is running somewhere location side, where there is database `MS SQL Server Express 2008`. I am restoring in my place where there is `MS SQL Server 2012 Express` Database.

When I am trying to restore i am getting below error :

```
Msg 3101, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Exclusive access could not be obtained because the database is in use.
Msg 3013, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
RESTORE DATABASE is terminating abnormally.
```

I have gone through so many blogs & MSDB BOL after that as per above error message then i have change the 'Restrict_Access' from Multi_User To 'Single_User' Then able to restore. After restore i am getting this message

```
Processed 1032 pages for database 'SLQ', file 'PosData_Data' on file 1.
Processed 1 pages for database 'SLQ', file 'PosData_Log' on file 1.
Converting database 'SLQ' from version 661 to the current version 706.
Database 'SLQ' running the upgrade step from version 661 to version 668.
Database 'SLQ' running the upgrade step from version 668 to version 669.
Database 'SLQ' running the upgrade step from version 669 to version 670.
Database 'SLQ' running the upgrade step from version 670 to version 671.
Database 'SLQ' running the upgrade step from version 671 to version 672.
Database 'SLQ' running the upgrade step from version 672 to version 673.
Database 'SLQ' running the upgrade step from version 673 to version 674.
Database 'SLQ' running the upgrade step from version 674 to version 675.
Database 'SLQ' running the upgrade step from version 675 to version 676.
Database 'SLQ' running the upgrade step from version 676 to version 677.
Database 'SLQ' running the upgrade step from version 677 to version 679.
Database 'SLQ' running the upgrade step from version 679 to version 680.
Database 'SLQ' running the upgrade step from version 680 to version 681.
Database 'SLQ' running the upgrade step from version 681 to version 682.
Database 'SLQ' running the upgrade step from version 682 to version 683.
Database 'SLQ' running the upgrade step from version 683 to version 684.
Database 'SLQ' running the upgrade step from version 684 to version 685.
Database 'SLQ' running the upgrade step from version 685 to version 686.
Database 'SLQ' running the upgrade step from version 686 to version 687.
Database 'SLQ' running the upgrade step from version 687 to version 688.
Database 'SLQ' running the upgrade step from version 688 to version 689.
Database 'SLQ' running the upgrade step from version 689 to version 690.
Database 'SLQ' running the upgrade step from version 690 to version 691.
Database 'SLQ' running the upgrade step from version 691 to version 692.
Database 'SLQ' running the upgrade step from version 692 to version 693.
Database 'SLQ' running the upgrade step from version 693 to version 694.
Database 'SLQ' running the upgrade step from version 694 to version 695.
Database 'SLQ' running the upgrade step from version 695 to version 696.
Database 'SLQ' running the upgrade step from version 696 to version 697.
Database 'SLQ' running the upgrade step from version 697 to version 698.
Database 'SLQ' running the upgrade step from version 698 to version 699.
Database 'SLQ' running the upgrade step from version 699 to version 700.
Database 'SLQ' running the upgrade step from version 700 to version 701.
Database 'SLQ' running the upgrade step from version 701 to version 702.
Database 'SLQ' running the upgrade step from version 702 to version 703.
Database 'SLQ' running the upgrade step from version 703 to version 704.
Database 'SLQ' running the upgrade step from version 704 to version 705.
Database 'SLQ' running the upgrade step from version 705 to version 706.
RESTORE DATABASE successfully processed 1033 pages in 0.812 seconds (9.938 MB/sec).
```

After Restore i have notice automatically `Restrict_Access` mode change from `Single_User` to `Multi_User`.
Why i am getting such type of message after `Restore verifyonly from Disk` TSQL Query & after restoring the above version message.

Any Suggestion regarding this concern will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Here is what I think is happening.

Error 1:

> Attempting to restore this backup may encounter storage space
>   problems. Subsequent messages will provide details. The path specified
>   by "C:\Software Lab\Database\SLQ.mdf" is not in a valid directory.
>   Directory lookup for the file "C:\Software Lab\Database\SLQ_Log.ldf"
>   failed with the operating system error 3(The system cannot find the
>   path specified.). The backup set on file 1 is valid.

The database you are trying to restore (verifyonly) had its files located on C:\software lab\database.  I'm guessing you don't have that directory on you local computer.  To prevent these messages, you'd need to add `MOVE` commands to your restore verify only script to point to directories that actually exist on your local computer.

Error 2:

> Exclusive access could not be obtained because the database is in use.

This 'sounds' like you're actually in the database you're trying to restore.  Make sure you are in `MASTER` before initiating the `RESTORE` 
command.

You're seeing these messages

> Converting database 'SLQ' from version 661 to the current version 706.
>
> Database 'SLQ' running the upgrade step from version 661 to version668.
>
> Database 'SLQ' running the upgrade step from version 668 to version
>   669.

because you are restoring a database that was created on an older version of Sql Server and is now being restored to a later version of Sql Server.  This requires an automatic upgrade of the database.

Because the database that was restored was already in MULTI_USER mode when it was backed up from the original source, upon successful restore, the database is placed in MULTI_USER mode (the same mode it was when backed up)